# How to return integer & char * variable in C++ native dll in a sametime?

Tags: c++

I tried to build a dll which could return the `int` and `char *` in Visual Studio in Windows, however it occurred the memory leaks, I builded this dll for other language, of course, in today's PCs, the memory is very large that I could ignore this bug completely, however I thought I would try my best to my everything. How to resolve this issue? I'm not familiar with C++, I have seen many web pages to check how to build a dll. I wish I could return multiple char * in the future when this problem has been resolved, any suggestions?

```
int   __stdcall  postsbinv(char ** retstring)
{
    std::wstring wstrinvnum = L"1215265152";
    size_t outputSize = wstrinvnum.length() + 1; // +1 for null terminator
    char * retinvnumtemp = new char[outputSize];//memory leaks
    size_t charsConverted = 0;
    const wchar_t * wchar_invnum = wstrinvnum.c_str();
    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, retinvnumtemp, outputSize, wchar_invnum, wstrinvnum.length());//convert the utf-16 to ascii
    *retstring = retinvnumtemp;//point to the char *
    return 0;
}
```

PS: for using by other language, I have use the char *

Comment: The best way is to provide a separate function your callers can use to free the data you return, this way the allocation mechanism is abstracted.

Answer (score 3):

If you are allocating memory with `new` you need to release it with `delete` and that's going to be a problem if the caller is in another language.

So you will need to provide a second function to release the memory.

```
int __stdcall postsbinv(char** retstring)
{
    *retstring = new char[outputSize];
}

void __stdcall free_sbinv(char** retstring)
{
    if (*retstring)
        delete[] *retstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to improve your code:

```
char *retinvnumtemp = new char[outputSize];

if(retinvnumtemp==NULL) {
    // enter code here
} else {
    // enter code here
}
```

And also to prevent from memory leaks you should use

delete []  retinvnumtemp;